# How to get the filename from input type=file html element using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

In Google Chrome browser, i have tried several way + following and none is giving me the value of the file name which was attached, after validation i will submit the file. But always its undefined or val() does not found..

How to resolve it?

```
console.log($("input[name='attachment[]']"));
/* Output:
[
<input type=​"file" name=​"attachment[]​" id=​"attachment">​
, 
<input type=​"file" name=​"attachment[]​" id=​"attachment">​
, 
<input type=​"file" name=​"attachment[]​" id=​"attachment">​
]
*/

$.each($("input[name='attachment[]']"), function(i,v) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(v); //v.val() does not exist... even uploaded a file and showing file

});

/* Output: 
0
<input type=​"file" name=​"attachment[]​" id=​"attachment">​
1
<input type=​"file" name=​"attachment[]​" id=​"attachment">​
2
<input type=​"file" name=​"attachment[]​" id=​"attachment">​
*/

return false;
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HttmlinputElement> has no mehtod 'val'` thats what it returns while trying with `$(v).val()`.

Comment: seriously? `$(v)` returns a jquery object

Comment: Side note: an `id` should be unique. Use for example `attachment1`, `attachment2`, ..., `attachmentn`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("input[name='attachment[]']").each(function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
    console.log(fileName);
});
```

You can't get the full path of the file, because it depends on the browser you use. The only common cross-browser value for an input file is the name of the file.

Answer (score 14):

I'd suggest something akin to the following:

```
​$('input:file').change(
    function(e){
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
    });​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nSf7w/).

If you're allowing for multiple files to be uploaded, using the `multiple` attribute, then to get each of the names:

```
$('input:file').change(
    function(e){
        var f = e.target.files,
            len = f.length;
        for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
            console.log(f[i].name);
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nSf7w/1/).

**NOTE: in current browser versions, `f[i].fileName` should be `f[i].name`.**

Comment: Should now be `.name` instead of `.fileName`.

Comment: I can confirm that it's now `.name` instead of `.fileName`. It might be a good thing to edit the answer :)

Answer (score 7):

The `<input type=file>` element has a zero-indexed [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) accessed through its member variable `files`.

You can access that list through a query selector:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files
```

And you can access the file name with dot notation:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0].name
```

It should be noted that in Chrome 53, Firefox 49, and the current [W3C spec for the FileAPI](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#filelist-section), `files` is an Array-like list not an actual array. You can access each file object through its index, but you won't have access to any array prototypes without first converting the list to an array.

Answer (score 0):

for

```
<input type="file" mutiple onchange="getSongs(this.files)"/>
```

use

```
function getSongs(files){
  ...
  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
     file=files[i];
     filename=file.fileName;
  }
}
```

if the input is just for single file, just use the name attribute

```
$("type=['file']").attr('name');
```

Comment: It would actually be: filename=file.name;