# PHP/HTML how to get filename from form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have following code:

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
       <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

How can i get the name of file i upload so i can save the path to database? I need only name of file, not the whole path. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicatie of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683192/how-to-get-the-filename-from-input-type-file-html-element-using-javascript-or-jq) SO question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
```

Comment: @AMAGR your welcome, you can mark my answer as answer.